# How to implement touch prop in Window component in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/windows#windows

```
<v-window
   v-model="window"
   :touch = "swipe"        
>
```

How to provide a custom left and right function when swiped left or right? The way I did is not working because I cannot access the variables I need and cannot call functions in methods.

```
export default {
  name :'test',
  data() {
    return {
      window: 0,
      length1:20,
      swipe: {
        length2:11,
        left: function() {
            //access both length1 and length2 here//
        },
        right:  function() {

        },
     }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call functions directly from `v-window` with `:touch`, instead of data.
Works for me.

```html
<v-window
   v-model="window"
   :touch="{left: onSwipeLeft, right: onSwipeRight}"        
>
```

```js
methods: {
  onSwipeLeft() {
   //do something with this.length1  or this.length2
  },
  onSwipeRight() {
   //exc
  }
}
```